# Which is a better extension language for speed optimization for python c or c++

Tags: c++, python, c

Would it be better to use c or c++ for handling computationally intensive tasks in a python program, where speed matters above all. Is there much of a difference between the two ? Which is more cleaner?

Comment: You can write very performant code in either, it's not going to matter. I will say though that this to me is a case of "if you have to ask you probably can't do it".  Writing highly optimized code is hard and requires a fair amount of knowledge and experience.  Having asked this question I can say you probably aren't there yet, though that doesn't mean you shouldn't start learning now!

Answer (score 1):

Well, C++ is supposed to be a superset of C. So you can write C programs in C++ and get the same amount of speed. It really depends on what you need to accomplish.

If you don't need any of C++'s features (OOP, templates, exceptions, etc), then C should be fine.

Of course, if you're already comfortable writing in Python, and you need a little more oomph, then you should give [Cython](http://cython.org/) a look.

Comment: C++ is supposed to be a superset of C... but its not :/

Comment: I started with the word "technically", then I realized that it wasn't quite accurate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both are compiled to native code and usually with the same compiler and thus the same compiler optimizations available. The performance difference you pay for supporting C++ language constructs should be negligible. Choose the one you prefer / the one that integrates better with Python / the one that integrates better with other native libraries you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The runtime performance you gain from using C++ versus C is negligible. In terms of integrating the code with your Python program (and most other languages) it is almost always easier to do with C. In fact if you're using ctypes to load and run the code (which I'd recommend), you still need to write a C interface around the C++ library.

Comment: Unless you use a library like boost::python or swig, then it might be easier to use C++ because you don't have to deal with Python API, which is sometimes not easy to get right.

Comment: ctypes does not require you to deal with the Python API. It's by far the simplest way to interact with a C library from Python. http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) it is easy to generate C++ wrappers.

Interactions to CPython are all done using the [CPython C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/), which is perfectly accessible from C++ (yay!). In the past when I have done some SWIG programming I did the *actual* code in "normal C" and then just wrapped the access via the generated SWIG classes -- this was just the easy method I found :)

As far as "performance":

1. Favor good algorithms, appropriate data-structures, and clean designs.
2. Get it working, benchmark, and only *then* -- if it even matters -- worry about the 3%. (This may mean *don't write it in C/C++ at all!* Also, benchmarking may need to come first for applications with stringent functional requirements to test for feasibility.)
3. Calling into an extension method can be *relatively expensive*; it may not always be justified.
4. **"It just doesn't matter"** - both C and C++ have countless high-performance applications/games/libraries. That is, choosing one does not inherently "limit performance" :)

(One of the biggest advantages I found with CPython extension modules was the ability to *release* the GIL and thus be able to have truly threaded code -- of course, the CPython C API can [generally] only be safely accessed while the GIL is acquired.)

Happy code.